# what will be the time taken for a session to timeout itself?

Tags: session

when an user is using the any web application  which sets session ,
what will be the default time taken for the session to unset itself

note: we are not unsetting i am asking about the default time taken where the session gets unset by itself

Comment: That depends on the language/session implementation you are using. So what language/session implementation do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Session is a state that is managed by a web application server. Every server (Tomcat, WebSphere, IIS, Glassfish, etc., etc.) all have default timeouts, somewhere in the 20-minute range.

Applications deployed on the web server can normally override the default settings for the server. Depending on the language, operating system, and server technology your timeout (and how to detect how long it is) will be different.

Comment: k thanks for ur effort i am using .net when it is working on firefox when the session will timeout

Comment: @gumbo 
: k thanks for ur effort i am using .net when it is working on firefox when the session will timeout –

Comment: As Kangkan pointed out, the default is 20 minutes and the browser is completely irrelevant. Assuming the application is being served by IIS, you would need to check the settings of the application pool, the web site / virtual directory, and of course the Web.config of the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

The session is a server side state management technique and is not dependent on the client side browser. The default timeout varies from one to the other server side technologies. As you are working with .net, the default timeout is 20 minutes. And this is independent of whether you are using IE or Firefox or any other browser.

I shall also request you to disclose if you have any issue with the same. A lot of team complains that though they set the timeout with a figure other than the default timeout, the session always times out after the default timeout period.